# is it possible to modify json objects in CLI?

Tags: python, json, linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have thousands of files containing a JSON objects
such as

```
{ "mykey" :"myvalue"}
```

and I have to add a key-value into each files
eg.

```
{ "mykey" :"myvalue", "newkey": "newvalue"}
```

I know I can easily come up Python script to do it.  Is there a easier way to do that in CLI? Something like

```
   addjson "newkey" "newvalue" myfile*.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the json node.js module.
After getting node.js you can install it with `sudo npm install -g json`

Usage `json -I -f myfile.json -e 'this.newkey="newvalue"'`

Only one file at the same time but as you said, you can use python
or an example with a for loop in bash: `for i in $(ls myfile*.json); do json -I -f $i -e 'this.newkey="newvalue"'; done`

Documentation: http://trentm.com/json/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this.

Add key value pair:

```
echo '{ "mykey" :"myvalue"}' | jq '. + {"newkey":"newvalue"}'
```

For more info on `jq` refer [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and [Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook)